# Typo in the angular-ng-disable tag

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

I think that the [angular-ng-disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-disable) tag should be renamed to **angular-ng-disabled**, since the directive itself is named [`ngDisabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled).

I don't know how to submit such a change request so I'm asking here.

**Edit**

As @g00glen00b stated, I'm not sure if we really need this, I came across when reading a question with this tag.

So I searched for other angular directives tags (I searched [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) for *angular-ng*) and found the [angular-ngselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ngselect) which, AFAIK, such directive doesn't even exist - I know there's the [ngSelected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) directive, but that tag is somewhat "vague".

I also noticed that there are inconsistencies in angular directives tags, some tags has hyphen after the *ng* ([angular-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-if), [angular-ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-class)) and other doesn't ([angular-ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ngmodel), [angular-nglist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-nglist)).

It's not that important of course, but it might trigger one's Obsessive–compulsive disorder.

Comment: [Only moderators can rename a tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag)

Comment: Thanks @Div, so i'll wait for a moderator to review my change request

Comment: Yes, actually they might be create a new tag and merge it with an old one.

Comment: There are just 56 questions with the tag... anyone can do it.

Comment: @Braiam Anyone can if the other tag already exists, but if it doesn't and they have to create it, then they'd have to wait for tag wiki edit approval... unless they're 20k+ rep

Comment: To be honest, if it's 56 questions, do we really need this tag? (either `angular-ng-disable` or `angular-ng-disabled`).